# I have a hf vertical antenna I'd like to put on my high-rise balcony

Tags: antenna

If I mount an HF vertical antenna at say a 45 degree angle to avoid a balcony ceiling, what do you suppose might happen?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: You get a slanted antenna! (Sorry, could not resist)

Answer (score 2):

The polarization plane will be rotated by 45 degrees, and the radiation pattern will be slightly altered.

It's probably no problem in practice. Dipoles make popular HF antennas, and those are usually installed fully horizontal.